# Local host is not accessible running docker linux containers in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have a react image running in docker windows with Linux containers. As the server is up and running on the 3000 port. I am not able to access the HTTP://localhost:3000, is there any problem.

Comment: Share the docker commands you tried to run the container. Port forwarding should be specified with -p option

Comment: @Sandeep This is the command which I am running.

"
docker run 2c60587ebf9d 
"

Comment: @Sandeep, Running in the local window system with a Linux container option.

Comment: try `docker run -p 3000:3000 2c60587ebf9d`

Comment: `-p<dockerHostPort>:<containerPort>` will forward container port to host port. You can check [container-networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed,

Port publishing should be done in order to access the docker container application on it. We can do it with -p/--publish option as following

`docker run -p <dockerHostPort>:<containerPort> <docker_image_or_id>`

This will forward container port `<containerPort>` to host port `<dockerHostPort>`. You can check [container-networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) for reference as we could publish all ports of container to host if there is such requirement.